# Using Faker with Pandas (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, faker

I have imported a csv into data frame and want to use faker to mask the First and Last names.

I am using the following code to call the function (list comprehension)

```
MasterDE['FirstName'] = [fake.first_name for i in range(MasterDE.FirstName.size)]

MasterDE['LastName'] = [fake.last_name for i in range(MasterDE.FirstName.size)]
```

When I try to inspect the data, I get this:

[image]

I would like to have the actual values and not this description. Will appreciate pointers on this.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was wrong. I missed out the parentheses after calling the method.

```
MasterDE['LastName'] = [fake.last_name() for i in range(MasterDE.LastName.size)]
```

works fine.